# Gridview Sorting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I tried to implement sorting with optimized paging but when I try to sort, nothing happens. The sort header's design changes and that's it.

Gridview:

```
<div align="center">

     <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSupplier" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetSuppliers"
        TypeName="Supplier" EnablePaging="True" MaximumRowsParameterName="PageSize" SelectCountMethod="GetRowsCount" StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRow" SortParameterName="sortBy">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>


    <asp:GridView ID="supplierGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
         CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="odsSupplier"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" 
         Width="300px">

        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="button" CommandName="Ed" HeaderText="Edit" 
                Text="Edit">
                <ControlStyle Width="75px" />
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="75px" />
                <ItemStyle Width="75px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:ButtonField>

            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="button" CommandName="Del" HeaderText="Delete" 
                Text="Delete">
                <ControlStyle Width="75px" />
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="75px" />
                <ItemStyle Width="75px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:ButtonField>
        </Columns>

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Supplier Class

```
public DataView GetSuppliers(int StartRow, int PageSize)
{
    return GetData(StartRow, PageSize, "EquipmentSupplierID");
}

public DataView GetSuppliers(int StartRow, int PageSize, string sortBy)
{
    return GetData(StartRow, PageSize, sortBy);
}

public DataView GetSuppliers(string sortBy)
{
    return GetData(int.MaxValue, 0, sortBy);
}

private DataView GetData(int StartRow, int PageSize, string sortBy)
{
    dbconn db = new dbconn();
    return db.getSupplierData(StartRow, PageSize, sortBy).DefaultView;
}

public int GetRowsCount()
{
    dbconn db = new dbconn();
    return db.getSupplierCount();
}
```

dbconn Class

```
public int getSupplierCount()
{
    open();
    setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM equipmentsupplier");
    MySqlDataReader msdr = executeReader();
    msdr.Read();
    int count = int.Parse(msdr["Count"].ToString());
    close();
    return count;
}

public DataTable getSupplierData(int StartRow, int PageSize, string sortBy)
{
    open();
    setQuery("SELECT * from equipmentsupplier ORDER BY ?SORT LIMIT ?StartRow, ?Total;");
    setParameter("StartRow", StartRow);
    setParameter("Total", PageSize);
    setParameter("SORT", sortBy);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(executeReader());
    return dt;
}
```

The queries are returning the right data when I sort it, but its just not showing on my gridview.

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanel outside your gridview?

Comment: nope, i'm not using an update panel. When I click on the headers, the column highlights but the data shown on the gridview is not being sorted

Answer (score 0):

@user2103743 Change all buttonfields to templatefield